# Copy directory from SharePoint site to local drive

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, batch-file, dos

As part of a larger batch script, I need to copy a directory from a TFS SharePoint site down on to the local drive. So something like:

```
copy "http://mySharePointSite/sites/MyProjectCollection/MyTeamProject/Shared Documents/Some Folder" C:\Temp
```

Any ideas how I would do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have local network access to the machine running SharePoint, you can use a UNC path to access the files directly.

```
\\servername\sitename\library\
```

The `sitename` is only used if you're actually accessing a sub site, otherwise it's just `\\servername\library\`

The path may be slightly different for team projects, but you should be able to find the correct path by browsing to it in Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Matthew. I also needed to enable UNC access on the server by installing the "Desktop Experience" feature (see http://www.knowledgeexchanger.com/other-development-tips/accessing-sharepoint-folders-using-unc/). Along with what you wrote provides the full solution. The path to use is "\\servername\sites\project collection name\team project name\Shared Documents".